# How to connect Amazon ElastiCache for Redis nodes enabled with in-transit encryption using redis-cli from windows server and/ from redis GUI client

Tags: redis-cli, amazon-elasticache, redisclient

I have a AWS elasticache(cluster mode disabled) with encryption at rest & encryption-in-transit enabled and trying to use redis-cli to connect from windows server (within same vpc).

Trying to connect to the RedisCluster from the server by following command

redis-cli -h  - p 6379

I'm able to connect and see the endpoint
Master......awsamazon.com:6379>

But when I try to run redis commands the command prompt just hangs up infinitely without any output.

Help me solve this issue.

Note: I'm trying to  connect from  windows server.

When I use this command-
redis-cli -h master.****awsamazon.com.xx --tls - p 6379
It gives an error -  "--tls" bad number of arguments

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I don't know about windows, but in linux to enable `--tls` option, when installing `redis-cli`, you need to build with `make BUILD_TLS=yes` instead of just running `make`. More details https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/encryption/

Answer (score 0):

In case of redis with encryption-in-transit enabled, you need to connect using "stunnel". Please try installing stunnel and configure endpoints and ports according to [this](https://medium.com/@rajeevpmr/remote-redis-connection-using-stunnel-5817ad6861ff)